# Proof regarding differential function and limits

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

[image]

Hey do you think I did alright trying to prove these questions?

a.

Let $f: R->R$, $ \ \
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x&x\ne 0\\
1&x=0
\end{cases}.
$

And let $x_{0} = 0$. By the algebra of continuous functions $f$ is differentiable on the deleted neighbour of 0, but $f$ is not continuous at 0, therefore not differentiable at 0.

b.

$f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$, therefore

$\lim _{x\to x_0}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=f\left(x_0\right)$

Now we check if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$

$f'(x_0)=\lim _{x\to x_0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_0\right)\right)}{x-x_0}$

We have $\frac{"0"}{0}$, therefore we use L'Hopital

$\lim _{x\to x_0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_0\right)\right)}{x-x_0}=\lim \:_{x\to \:x_0}\left(\:f'\left(x\right)\right)=L$

Therefore $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

Comment: Looks good to me. Though it should be algebra of differentiable, not continuous functions, but you probably meant that.

Comment: In part (a), you should verify that $f'(x)$ converges as $x \to 0$.  It is trivially true for your example  but it is one of the conditions you need to meet.